# Array.prototype.filter automatically filtering out falsey value

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, functional-programming

Does the filter function automatically filter out falsey values such as false, null, or undefined? If so, how to stop it from doing that.

I need to filter out all 0 in an array, so I used array.filter callback, and I realized that the filter function removes falsey values, even when I want to keep them. Is there a way around this?

EDIT: This is the code that I have, and doing a deep comparison didn't return the falsey values.

```
function removeZero(arr) {
  return arr.filter(function(element){
    if(element!==0){
      return element;
    }
  });
}
```

EDIT 2: Here's the repl.it link that contains a test array content, and when I ran it the result filters out false, null, and undefined. https://repl.it/BAiK

Comment: Your code would probably help here. The filter function will remove what you ask it to remove. If it's removing `null` or `undefined` it's because *that's what you asked it to do*

Comment: If an answer solves your issue, accept it by clicking the green check in the left side of the answer. In that way, the next people visiting this question will know better what is an answer that solves your issue.

Comment: I changed the example to show what happens with objects also. Can you show us the array contents?

Comment: I edited my answer with your code fixed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `!==` operator

```
[1,2,3,0,[],{},false,undefined].filter(function(e){return e !== 0})
// Output: [1, 2, 3, Array[0], Object, false, undefined]
```

compare with the output of the `!=` operator (which you don't want to use)

```
[1,2,3,0,[],{},false,undefined].filter(function(e){return e != 0})
// Output: [1, 2, 3, Object, undefined]
```

This is the code you provided https://repl.it/BAiK

```
var removeZeros = function (arr) {
  return arr.filter(function(element){
    if(element!==0){
      return element; // here is the error, you need to return a boolean. (true to add element to final array, false to ignore element)
    }
  });
}

console.log(removeZeros([false, 1, 2, 3, null, 0, 4, undefined, 5, 0]));
// Output: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
```

You see, the return value for the filter function needs to be a boolean value, not the element you want to return. When you return false, the element is not added to the final array, when you return true, the element being processed is returned. See my edit with your code fixed

This is your code fixed

```
var removeZeros = function (arr) {
  return arr.filter(function(element){
    return element !== 0 // this returns a boolean
  });
}

console.log(removeZeros([false, 1, 2, 3, null, 0, 4, undefined, 5, 0]));
// Output: [ false, 1, 2, 3, null, 4, undefined, 5 ]
```

Comment: Note that the only entry where `!=` is different is with the boolean `false` value. Not that you should just use `!==` anyway.

Comment: I think the filter function filters out falsey value anyways. At least when I used deep comparison, it still filtered out the falsey values. And I was looking for a way to override or get around that.

Comment: @jperelli please see the edit. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You see, the return value for the filter function needs to be a boolean value, not the element you want to return. When you return false, the element is not added to the final array, when you return true, the element being processed is returned. See my edit with your code fixed

Answer (score 1):

```js
var result = [1, 2, 3, 0, false, undefined, null, -1].filter(
    function (e) { 
        return e !== 0;
    });
document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = result.reduce(function (r, a) { return r + '\n    ' + a + ' [' + (typeof a) + ']'; }, '[') + '\n]';
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

your example does not return true, but the value itselft, which is evaluated. `Array.filter()` include the element if the return value is truthy.

```
function removeZero(arr) {
    return arr.filter(function(element) {
        if (element !== 0){
            return element; // <-- falsy values are not true.
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to convert the JSON string back to an array, since I still want the array returned.

Comment: just take result. it is an array.

Answer (score 1):

just

```js
[1,2,3,0,[],{},false,undefined].filter(Boolean)  // return [1, 2, 3, [], {}]
```

here `Boolean` is a function, which when all the `falsy value` come in, it will return `false`